# Copy same element multiple times in the same column, Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to copy elements of a column 3 times.

That is,

From
DataFrame = [A, B, C]

To
DataFrame = [A, A, A, B, B, B, C, C, C]

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awKVP.png)  -> [DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzghb.png)

Can this be achieved by some lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this concatenating dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Values": ["A", "B", "C"]})

# output
  Values
0   A
1   B
2   C


pd.concat([df, df, df]).sort_values("Values")

# output
  Values
0   A
0   A
0   A
1   B
1   B
1   B
2   C
2   C
2   C
```

Or if you would like to use *apply* for some reason you can do this in that weird way:

```
import itertools

pd.DataFrame(
    itertools.chain(*df.Values.apply(lambda x: 3 * [x]).to_list()), 
    columns=df.columns
    )

# output
  Values
0      A
1      A
2      A
3      B
4      B
5      B
6      C
7      C
8      C
```